# TestNG @AfterTest called without executing all Tests

Tags: maven, jenkins, testng, testng-eclipse

I am facing different issue when I run test cases. 
I have around 50 test cases. 
During the test run suddenly it is calling @AfterTest and completing the test run. At the end it ran only 10 test cases. Every run it is giving different no.of ran test cases. (Like 4, 10, 15 but not running all test cases)

Questions: 
@AfterTest supposed to call after executing all @Test methods. 
Is there any process behind will terminate the @Test methods execution and call @AfterTest method? How debug this kind of failures?

Could someone please help me in this?

I am using Appium to run the test cases. Whenever Appium throws uncaught exception, it is coming out the test block and executing AfterTest block without executing all test cases.

Logs from Appium:

2018-06-12 00:56:21:720 - error: uncaughtException: write EPIPE date=Tue Jun 12 2018 00:56:21 GMT+0530 (IST), pid=68705, uid=503, gid=20, cwd=/Users/../Desktop/Automation/CodeBase/MyProject, execPath=/usr/local/bin/node, version=v8.9.4, argv=[/usr/local/bin/node, /usr/local/bin/appium, -a, 127.0.0.1, -p, 4721, -cp, 5721, -bp, 6721, --chromedriver-port, 7721, --no-reset, --log-level, debug, --local-timezone, --log, /Users/../target/AppiumLogs/appiumLogs_201.log], rss=194183168, heapTotal=137883648, heapUsed=129103560, external=213116, loadavg=[2.45849609375, 2.568359375, 2.4462890625], uptime=476242, trace=[column=11, file=util.js, function=_errnoException, line=1022, method=null, native=false, column=14, file=net.js, function=WriteWrap.afterWrite, line=867, method=afterWrite, native=false], stack=[Error: write EPIPE,     at _errnoException (util.js:1022:11),     at WriteWrap.afterWrite (net.js:867:14)]

Comment: Please edit your question and help provide a [minimal complete verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which can be used to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @KrishnanMahadevan Updated question with the logs. Thank you!